# Math Behind Producing Uniform Distribution

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I am familiar that if one can produce a uniform distribution, doing so, one can then produce random numbers for other types of distributions. I have tried reading some articles online but I am still confused as to how is one to produce random numbers from a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't *really* produce uniform values in a continuous interval -- if only because this would (with probability $1$) result in a number that cannot even be *written down* in finite space. Instead one can *approximate* such a distribution. For example as an uniform choice of numbers from the discrete set
$$ \{ n\cdot 2^{-53} \mid 0 < n \le 2^{53} \} $$
will approximate a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ well enough for many purposes.

Such a number can be produced by flipping a coin 53 times to produce 53 binary digits, or by any other source of random bits you have available.

Producing random *bits* is a nontrivial engineering challenge if you want them to be truly random. For many purposes a [pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (whose output isn't really random but can look at lot like it) will suffice. For information about creating true randomness, [random.org](https://www.random.org/randomness/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am wondering that if I use something like a Linear Congruential Generator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), would the outputs belong to a uniform distribution?

Comment: @stats555: A linear congruential generator is a quite poor PRNG by today's standards and is not really recommended for anything except very casual applications. The _frequencies_ of the values it produces are uniform, but there are simple patterns in the _sequence_ of values which can inadvertently ruin the advantages one tries to achieve by using randomness.

Comment: Thank you once again for your answer. I am reading the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Mathematical_definition) you provided, under the section labelled "Mathematical Definition" - the proof mentioned is far ahead of my understandings - but I will accept that it can be shown the results would have a uniform distribution.